# Conditionally replace values of multiple columns, from values of other multiple columns

Tags: r, replace, at-command, dplyr

Suppose I have this dataset:

```
set.seed (1234); 
data.frame(cbind(a=rep(c("si","no"),30),b=rnorm(60)),
           c=rep(c("d","e","f"),20))  %>% head()
```

[image: original dataset, first 6 cases]

Then I want to add many columns (in this example I only added two), to identify distinct cases between each group (in this case, column "a").

```
set.seed(1234); 
data.frame(cbind(a=rep(c("si","no"),30),b=rnorm(60)),c=rep(c("d","e","f"),20)) %>% 
group_by(a) %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(c(b,c)), .funs= list(dups_hash_ing= ~n_distinct(.)))
```

This code leaves the following dataset:

[image: dataset with distinct cases]

If I set the dataset with `dput`, the outcome is

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "si"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(22L, 
1L, 51L, 34L, 50L, 57L, 53L, 10L, 47L, 3L, 11L, 23L, 15L, 38L, 
58L, 39L, 41L, 17L, 28L, 21L, 37L, 45L, 29L, 46L, 32L, 48L, 56L, 
52L, 26L, 19L, 35L, 8L, 55L, 20L, 9L, 36L, 2L, 12L, 6L, 42L, 
49L, 43L, 59L, 54L, 31L, 13L, 60L, 44L, 14L, 30L, 7L, 5L, 16L, 
27L, 33L, 18L, 24L, 4L, 25L, 40L), .Label = c("-0.0997905884418961", 
"-0.151736536534977", "-0.198416273822079", "-0.254874652654534", 
"-0.274704218225806", "-0.304721068966714", "-0.324393300483657", 
"-0.400235237343163", "-0.415751788401515", "-0.50873701541522", 
"-0.538070788884863", "-0.60615111526422", "-0.659770093821306", 
"-0.684320344136007", "-0.789646852263761", "-0.933503340589868", 
"-0.965903210133575", "-1.07754212275943", "-1.11444896479736", 
"-1.60708093984972", "-2.07823754188738", "-2.7322195229558", 
"-2.85575865501923", "-3.23315213292314", "0.0295178303214797", 
"0.0326639575014441", "0.116845344986082", "0.162654708118265", 
"0.185513915583057", "0.186492083080971", "0.287709728313787", 
"0.311681028661359", "0.319160238648117", "0.413868915451097", 
"0.418057822385083", "0.42200837321742", "0.485226820569252", 
"0.487814635163685", "0.500694614280786", "0.594273774110513", 
"0.62021020366732", "0.629536099884472", "0.660212631820405", 
"0.677415500438328", "0.696768778564913", "0.700733515544461", 
"0.704180178465512", "0.760462361967838", "0.895171980275539", 
"0.912322161610113", "0.976031734922396", "1.1123628412626", 
"1.16910851401363", "1.17349757263239", "1.49349310261748", "1.84246362620766", 
"1.98373220068438", "2.16803253951933", "2.27348352044748", "2.91914013071762"
), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    a_dups_hash_ing = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b_dups_hash_ing = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), c_dups_hash_ing = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), groups = structure(list(
    a = structure(1:2, .Label = c("no", "si"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 
    22L, 24L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 
    46L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L), c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
    9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 
    33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 
    57L, 59L))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

---

**What I need to do, is replace, column by column, if the number of distinct cases is more than one per group, with the value of the original column.** I have to do this for more than 50 columns. An example of this will be provided for only one column with mutate:

```
  dplyr::mutate(b_dups_hash_ing= ifelse(>1,b,0))
```

I need to repeat the code provided above for many variables. This is very similar to a `mutate_at` (words in brackets is what I would do). The following example does not work, but is something I would do in an ideal world, just for your better understanding of my problem.

```
dplyr::mutate_at(vars(contains('_dups_hash_ing')), .funs = list(~ifelse(.>1,vars([original]),0)))
```

Comment: Please make this reproducible by setting a seed with `set.seed([some number here])`

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the output of the example is not relevant. I'm particularly interested in the function that makes it possible to replace values in the columns. I will do my best trying to edit the question, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I did what you asked. I added the seed. Thank you.

Comment: Try using `dput(dataset)`, where `dataset` might be a `dataframe`.

Comment: I did what you asked, @massisenergy. Please unvote your negative vote, if possible.

Comment: That's not me, just tried to make the question more comprehensible, with the suggestion.

Comment: Does your real data match your example data?  It seems odd to try to conditionally return the value of the original column or the number of distinct cases when the original columns are of different classes (i.e. `n_distinct()` returns an integer but the original columns are not of class integer).

Comment: @H1 what I would like to do is to detect if there are any distinct values in columns "b" or "c", within the rows that share the same value in column "a". I need to do detect differences within value in "a", for more than 50 variables, so first I need to detect if there are more than 1 distinct value in each of the variables that end with "_dup_hash_ing" (`ifelse(. > 1,`). If there are more than one value, I need that this column brings the value of the original column. Thanks by the way

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(contains('_dups_hash_ing')), ~ ifelse(. > 1, ., 0)) %>% head
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   a [2]
#>   a     b                  c     a_dups_hash_ing b_dups_hash_ing c_dups_hash_ing
#>   <fct> <fct>              <fct>           <dbl>           <int>           <int>
#> 1 si    -2.7322195229558   d                   0              30               3
#> 2 no    -0.09979058844189… e                   0              30               3
#> 3 si    0.976031734922396  f                   0              30               3
#> 4 no    0.413868915451097  d                   0              30               3
#> 5 si    0.912322161610113  e                   0              30               3
#> 6 no    1.98373220068438   f                   0              30               3
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do something like this:
`df  %>% dplyr::mutate(b_dups_hash_ing=ifelse(. > 1,b, 0)) %>% head`, but for more than 50 columns (I was wondering to do this by the function `mutate_at`, but I can't imagine how to do it).

Comment: Is there a predicate function that can be passed to mutate_if to select the columns you want or can you simply pass a numeric vector of positions to mutate_at(vars())?

Comment: I can simply pass a numeric vector of positions. I have a vector of names of columns, which are the original ones (`c(b,c)`), and a vector of column names that I created that should be of the same length, which are the ones that contain the suffix "_dup_hash_ing" (`contains('_dups_hash_ing')`). This is what I did in the previous step: `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(c(b,c)), .funs= list(dups_hash_ing= ~n_distinct(.)))`. Now that i can detect if there are more than one case per group (in column a), I can replace values with the original ones if there are more than one case per group.

Comment: Sorry. I dont speak english very well. I need to replace values in variables that contains "_dup_hash_ing" ("b_dup_hash_ing" and "c_dup_hash_ing") with the original variable ("b" and "c"), for each one, if the values of "_dup_hash_ing" are greater than 1.

Comment: I need a function that can do something like this: `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(c(b,c)), .funs= funs(`dups_hash_ing`=ifelse(n_distinct(.)>1, as.character(.),"")))` but by giving me the distinct values per row, no by group (a) (`group_by(a)`)